# Stable hash function to partition a set of number into m buckets to make the m bucket size balanced as possible

Tags: algorithm, hash, partition, data-partitioning

current algorithm is :

```
            d = {}
            for doc_id in request:
                    md5 = hashlib.md5()
                    md5.update(str(doc_id) + "_" +  request_id)
                    digest = md5.hexdigest()
                    k = int(digest, 16)
                    a = (k%720)/(720/16)
                    if a not in d:
                            d[a]=1
                    else:
                            d[a]=d[a]+1
```

request size are in (800, 1000) range

i calculate 1000 times of the algorithm,

the max(d[i])- min(d[j])  are avg in 20+

is there a method to make the 16 buckets size are balanced as possible

Comment: What's the idea behind `a = (k%720)/(720/16)`? Why not simply `a = k % number_of_buckets`? If `2**128` (the maximum value of an MD5 hash, plus 1) is not cleanly divisible by `number_of_buckets` it will produce some bias, but `2**128` is huge, so the bias is tiny.

Comment: @Thomas a = k % number_of_buckets.  make no difference,

Comment: I know, but that wasn't my question. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it can be done better *just* by changing the hash function. MD5 is not state of the art anymore, but it's still plenty random enough for something like this.

Let's look at some probability theory to see how good it might get if we used a perfectly uniform hash function. If you put 1000 elements into 16 buckets *entirely at random*, you'd expect 1000 / 16 = 62.5 elements per bucket on average. But what is the variance on this number?

To calculate this, consider a single bucket and a completely random bucket assignment. The probability that a particular element is assigned to this bucket is 1/16, and we have 1000 elements. So our distribution is equivalent to a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with n = 1000 and p = 1/16.

The variance of that distribution is given by n * p * (1 - p) ≈ 59. The standard deviation is sqrt(variance) ≈ 8, which gives you an idea of the order of magnitude of expected deviations from the mean. The binomial distribution isn't a normal distribution, but for numbers of this size it comes pretty close, so [we would expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#/media/File:Standard_deviation_diagram.svg) about 68% of bucket sizes to be within 8 of the mean. A value that deviates more than 20 from the mean is expected to happen in 0.6% of cases, according to my trusty TI-83 calculator, so with 1000 trials you're very likely to see some of those.

---

If the imbalance is really causing problems, you could change your partitioning code to use some type of [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing). A simple way is to use the target bucket plus one (modulo bucket count), until it finds one that's not full enough.

Note that you'll have a hard time finding the element again afterwards, unless you limit this bucket hopping, for example do it at most 3 times. This makes lookups more expensive because you need to look for the element in 4 buckets instead of just 1.

If you don't *need* to find elements afterwards, you could simply assign them to the least full bucket instead; then there's no need for hashing at all.

Comment: Current I need to find a stable algorithm to make the same doc_id into the same bucket.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas explained, even a cryptographic strength hash function - that effectively produces a pseudo-random value (but stable for each key) - will exhibit quite a bit of variance.  If you want to improve on that, you have a couple options:

- there's some variance in the #elements-per-bucket variance, so you could do something like looping i from 1 to 1000; appending `"_" + i` to your keys, and see which loop iteration produced the smallest `max(d[i])- min(d[j])` value; just remember to add the same `_i` when doing lookups

  - my company does something like that when packing keys in the morning for use throughout the day, to minimise worst-case collision chain length and hence memory use for our statically allocated two-dimensional array; basically `[#buckets][max-collisions]`; we change random number data used by the hash function rather than the keys, but either's possible
- exploit some knowledge of the keys (if they're amenable to that) - this is a bit of black art, but for example - numbers that tend to increment but might have occasional gaps often map better onto buckets with an identity hash (i.e. h(k) == k) than a cryptographic-strength hash; when you have two part keys - `doc_id` and `request_id` - you'd need to understand the typical values/patterns in both to have any chance of crafting a hash function with more-even-than-cryptographic distribution and try to combine them to get similarly dense but even packing

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have noted, the behavior you’re seeing is a consequence of the behavior of dropping balls into bins randomly and looking at the most-loaded and least-loaded buckets. Even with a purely random distribution, you’d expect to see a decent spread between these buckets.

An alternative is to use a different strategy for distributing items into buckets. Imagine that you have *two* hash functions rather than just one. If you hash each item and place it into the lesser-loaded of the two buckets it hashes to, the resulting distribution is significantly closer to uniform than if you just hash each item once. (This is sometimes called the “power of two choices”). Adding more hash functions beyond this does decrease the spread more, but not to the same degree as from one hash function to two.